# Sorting and Calculating Wage from Struct Array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, struct

I have to calculate the wage for each employee. How would I write a function to do this?
And how would I sort the employees according to their wage?
The data file looks like this: I think I have to convert int to string or the other way around. I know that The function for calculating wage is wrong. Thanks.

```
A.Smith                       20001 25 40
T.Philip                      20002 20 35
S.Long                        20003 15 50
G.Santos                      20004 30 30
F.Farkas                      20005 22 55
```

and this is my code that I am trying to write:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;


struct Record
{
    string name;
    int id;
    double rate;
    int hrWorked;
    double wage;

};

void read_file(string[], int); 
void calculate_wage(Record& payroll);


int main()
{
    int e = 5;    
    Record payroll[5];
    string s[5];

    cout << "Your entered file is: " << endl; 
    read_file(s, e);

    calculate_wage(payroll);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void read_file(string s[], int e)
{
    ifstream myFile;
    myFile.open("Project 3.dat");
    string str;
    int i = 0;

    if (myFile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myFile, str))
        {
            s[i++] = str;
            cout << str << endl;
        }

        myFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "No Data Found!" << endl;
    }

}

void calculate_wage (Record& payroll) // i know this part isnt right but im not sure what to do for this
{
    char emplresult[256];  // need to convert int to string
    payroll.wage = atoi(emplresult);
    payroll.rate = atoi(emplresult);
    payroll.hrWorked = atoi(emplresult);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        payroll[i].wage = payroll[i].rate * payroll[i].hrWorked;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is `read_file`? Why does your input look like employees have 4 traits (name, ID, something, something) and your `Record` have 5? The input format is very friendly so you can probably just do `std::cin >> r.name >> r.id >> r.hrWorked >> r.wage;`. Once you have your `Record`s look into `std::sort`.

Comment: Also go easy on the "convert int to string or the other way around" part. Just read the proper data type and use it as is. You shouldn't need to convert anything.

Comment: We can certainly help solve specific problems on StackOverflow, but it's beyond the site scope to design or write code for you. I also suspect this is a homework question - I've seen it many times before - and I *certainly* don't want to rob you of the learning opportunity of doing your own homework! If this is the case, your course materials will contain all the information you need to write the code.

Comment: Related: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.  I also recommend that you use `<cstdlib>` in preference to `<stdlib.h>` if you're writing new code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use std algorithms, it will make your code readable and maintainable. For example you can sort your objects with `std::sort`:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct Record
{
    Record(std::string name, double wage) : name(name), wage(wage) {};
    std::string name;
    int id;
    double rate;
    int hrWorked;
    double wage;

};

int main() {
    using Records = std::vector<Record>;
    Records records;
    records.push_back(Record("Pedro",20));
    records.push_back(Record("Andres",10));
    records.push_back(Record("Santiago",15));

    std::sort(records.begin(),records.end(),
              [](auto& lhs, auto& rhs) { 
                  return lhs.wage < rhs.wage; 
              });

    for (const auto& r : records) {
        std::cout << "Name: " << r.name << " wage: " << r.wage << "\n";
    }
}
```

which outputs the sorted records:

```
Name: Andres wage: 10
Name: Santiago wage: 15
Name: Pedro wage: 20
```

I hope this gives you inspiration for your code!